# Windows Server 2003: Moving a window causes 100% CPU in Performance

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance

Hey, I have a server running Windows 2003, the server seems to be slow when controlled remotely. I opened the performance monitor and moved the window, the CPU usage peaked to 100% for a moment, then it went back to being close to zero. Is that a normal situation?

Comment: What are you using to control the server remotely?

Comment: TeamViewer (remote control software)

Comment: Is your server fully patched?  That would help rule out a software bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Server 2003, all video acceleration is disabled by default, even if you have a full-blown 3D video card; this can make even drawing a window *painfully* slow (really wonder WTF were they thinking in Microsoft when they designed this).

Try to have a look at the advanced properties of the video card and enabling them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's pretty normal. The reality is that the performance monitor is extremely inaccurate for very brief events. Part of the problem is that it does some predictive averaging to ease its own load on the system, so when there is a sudden spike in activity it gets things a bit wrong due to the small sampling it has to work with. Of course if it stayed at 100% for any length of time it would be another matter entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using a Corporate license of TeamViewer since version 4. Only once have I had issues similar to your, and it was when I remoted into a consulting company, which specialized in IT security. Their firewalls and security were tighter than anything I have ever seen, so we were convinced that it was their firewall.

I would also wonder what kind of disks you have, SATA or SAS as SATA can hog processing power.

So I would do the following: Uninstall and reinstall TV just in case (pretty quick to do), and then check your firewall logs to see if anything is being blocked. You can also make sure that there is no proxy server set in the Security options, and in the Presentation settings set the quality to "Optimize Speed". You can also try unchecking "Use UDP" in the Advanced>Advanced Network Settings. Lastly, you did not say if you were using the VPN option, if so, try it without it as a test.